# JQuery UI Tabs - Modify link for tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

Is there a way to modify the link to a tab in jquery ui through jquery/javascript?

For example, my page layout has a query mechanism at the top, with several tabs underneath it.  When the user submits the query, I'd like append the query string to each of the tab links.  This works fine if I do full page refreshes when I submit the query, I just plug the query string in the link as the tabs are being built.  However, if I try to submit and get my results asynchronously, I need my tabs links to get updated.

Below is a snippet of my button click event event, I build a query string, then submit it like this:

```
    $.ajax({
                url: "/MyController/" + actionPrefix + "Index?q=" + query + extraParm + "#ui-tabs-" + selectedTab,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {
                    $(list).remove();
                    $(container).append(html);
                    $('li a.actionLink').unbind('click').click(function() {
                        //This was some code I was playing with to change tab links, but couldn't seem to get it working...                        
                    });
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The href is stored in the .data store.

You can use the following to change the url

```
$('#tabs').tabs('url' , tabIndex , url );
```

Another way see my answer to another SO question.

[Getting Target URL from jQuery-UI Tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359343/getting-target-url-from-jquery-ui-tabs/1359421#1359421)

This allows you to say the following to change the first tab url

```
$('#tabs a:first').data('href.tabs', 'someNewUrl');
```

Comment: why would something like this not work:                     $('#tabs a.actionLink').each(function() {
                        $(this).data('href.tabs', "http://www.google.com");
                    });

Comment: errr well you cant load google as it is cross domain. Is the url your using on the same domain?

Comment: yea, I tried a local domain and it worked, I just plugged google in there to test with. =)  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @redsquare he sure can on jQuery > = 1.5. Just add 'crossDomain:true' to your ajax() params.

Comment: Yes it's called jsonP (padded json). It was integrated into the JQuery core on version 1.5. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: @AlienWebguy - jsonp has been around long before jq 1.5:) In fact it was added in 1.2 http://docs.jquery.com/Release:jQuery_1.2/Ajax. What makes you think the OP is using jsonp endpoints since he mentions nothing about it! You cannot request html content remotely x-broswer. Sure you can use jsonp but that just refines down to script calls and not xhr.

Answer (score 4):

Above answer will not work in JQuery 1.9+ as describer [here](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#deprecated-url-method-and-use-of-title-attribute-use-aria-controls-attribute). To work with jquery ui tabs 1.9+ you have to do something like this

```
var tabs = $("#tabs");
var tab = $(tabs.data('uiTabs').tabs[TAB_INDEX]);
tab.find('.ui-tabs-anchor').attr('href', "NEW_URL");
// If cached initially. Remove cache then
tab.data( "loaded", false);
tabs.tabs( "option", "active", TAB_INDEX);
tabs.tabs("load", TAB_INDEX);
```

This will change the URL of tab at particular index and load that tab.

Comment: Thanks for keeping this question up to date for current versions of JQuery UI.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just change the href:

```
       success: function(html) {
            $(list).remove();
            $(container).append(html);
            $('li a.actionLink').attr('href',somethingNew);
        }
```

Comment: The href's on them are links like "#ui-tabs-1".  If I look at the generated html, shows the full href like "/MyController/Action"  However, if I do an "alert($(this).attr('href'), it shows up like "#ui-tabs-1".