# How can i keep the selected tab selected even after postback

Tags: c#, jquery

I have some listed tab controls on my aspx form which is as below

```
 <div id="tabs">
    <ul>

        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab B</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab C</a></li>

    </ul>
<div id="tabs-1"></div>
<div id="tabs-2"><asp:Button ID="someid" runat="server"/></div>
<div id="tabs-3"></div>
</div>
```

The navigation on mouse click on a tab is done by the following:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs();

    });
</script>
```

Now, my question is, How can i maintain the selected tab as it is even after postback.
For Example, I select Tab B that contains a Button which causes a postback on click.
 After the postback occurs Tab A regians the foucs and i have to manually select Tab B for adjuvent operations.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this Code will help you...

```
<div id="tabs">
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hidtab" Value="0" runat="server" />
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>

        </ul>

        <div id="tabs-1">
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_Click"/>
        </div>

        <div id="tabs-2">
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button2_Click"/>
        </div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var st= $(this).find("input[id*='hidtab']").val();
            if (st== null)
                st= 0;
            $('[id$=tabs]').tabs({ selected: st});
        });
    </script>

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    hidtab.Value = "0";
}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    hidtab.Value = "1";
}
```

Comment: @Kiranramchandran P , What is `tab_index.Value`..? Did you mean `hidtab.Value`..? Then fix the typo..

Comment: @Kiranramchandran How can i use it with Jquery UI Tabs?

Answer (score 5):

Initialize tabs with the [cookie](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#option-cookie) option specified.   [Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/DKvVM/)

```
$(function () {
   $("#tabs").tabs({ cookie: { expires: 30 } });
});
```

You need the jQuery [Cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/jquery.cookie.js)..

Comment: Still the problem persists

Comment: You need to use jQuery cookie plugin.. Are you using it...?

Comment: yeah..Now it does, but using cookies won't be fruitful in my application. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can track it by your URL like they did in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359343/getting-target-url-from-jquery-ui-tabs).
The following code is just for example and can be done a lot nicer. I used the `active` property from the [jquery ui tabs](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active). it works with the index of the element but perhaps its working with the #hash aswell did not test it. so in the example below i get the index of the tab and use it with `active` property;

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>

        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab B</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab C</a></li>

    </ul>
<div id="tabs-1"></div>
<div id="tabs-2"><asp:Button ID="someid" runat="server"/></div>
<div id="tabs-3"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var tabsOpts = {}, 
            activeTab, activeTabIndex,
            urlCheck = doucment.location.href.split('#');

        // urlCheck is an array so when there is more then one result
        // there is a hash found in the URL
        if( urlCheck.length > 1 ) {
            activeTab = urlCheck[1];

            // getting the index from the link
            activeTabIndex = $("#tabs li a[href="+ activeTab +"]").index();

            // create new object options for the tabs
            tabsOpts = { active: activeTabIndex };
        }

        $("#tabs").tabs(tabsOpts)
        .find('li a').each(function() {
            // get URL from the tab href
            var href = $.data(this, 'href.tabs');
            // set URL with the href from your tab
            document.location = href;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Client Side solution:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_initializeRequest(IniciaRequest);
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
var currentTab;

function IniciaRequest(sender, arg) {
  var _Instance = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

  if (_Instance.get_isInAsyncPostBack()) {
    window.alert("Existe un proceso en marcha. Espere");
    arg.set_cancel(true);
  }
}

function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
  //Persiste el valor del indice del TAB actual del control Jquery para mantener el tab actual seleccionado luego del Postback.
  if ($get('hdCurrentTab') != null) {
    currentTab = $get('hdCurrentTab').value;
  }
  //----
}

function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
  //Permite visualiza el control JQuery TAB dentro de ventanas modales AJAX.
  if (sender._postBackSettings.panelsToUpdate != null) {
    $("#tabs").tabs();

    //Persiste el valor del indice del TAB actual del control Jquery para mantener el tab actual seleccionado luego del Postback.
    if ($get('hdCurrentTab') != null) {
      $get('hdCurrentTab').value = currentTab;
      $("#tabs").tabs({ active: currentTab });
    }
    //----
  }
  //----
}
</script>
```

HTML on Page:

```html
<input id="hdCurrentTab" type="hidden" value="0" />
<div id="tabs" style="width:97%;margin: auto; font-family: verdana, tahoma, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 11px;">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1" onclick="$get('hdCurrentTab').value = '0';">TAB1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2" onclick="$get('hdCurrentTab').value = '1';">TAB2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1"></div>
  <div id="tabs-2"></div>
</div>
```

TAB remains selected after postbacks.